# Uploading image to WordPress API in Postman using form-data does not work, but using binary does

Tags: wordpress, next.js, file-upload, postman

I have a WordPress API endpoint for uploading media to WordPress `wp-json/wp/v2/media`

When I try it on Postman, when I use the `form-data`, it will not fail and will return an error like this:

[image]

but when I try to use binary, it will successfully upload it to WordPress, and looks like this:

[image]

Now, in my next.js app, I use the snippet provided by postman to mimic the api call. However, I am not sure how to make the form submission be binary instead of form-data. Also, I get a cors issue when doing so. I believe, the first step to fix the issue is to figure out how to turn the form-data to binary. Any help is highly appreciated.